# why it shows selected value twice in laravel drop down option value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

**Database table**

```
 jobcategories
 id | name
 1  | IT
 2  | MBA
 3  | Pharmacy
```

I save one of this value by selecting drop down value into jobdetails table.

```
jobdetails
id | job_title | jobcategory_id | ...
1  | Software Engg. | 1

// JobDetail model
public function jobcategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('JobCategory');
}

// JobCategory model
public function jobdetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('JobDetail', 'jobcategories');
}
```

**Controller to save**

```
    public function postAddJobs() {
    $input = Input::all();

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $jobdetails = JobDetail::create(array
        (   
         'job_title' => $input['title'],
          .........
        )
    );
    }
    if(isset($input['category'])){
        foreach($input['category'] as $catID){
            $jcat = JobCategory::find($catID);
            $jobdetails->jobcategory()->associate($jcat);
            $jobdetails->save();
        }
    }
```

**view file from where I save**

```
    <select name="category[]" class="details">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
    @foreach(JobCategory::all() as $jcat)     
       <option value="{{ $jcat->id }}">{{ $jcat->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
```

**Edit controller**

```
    public function getJobEdit($id)
    {
    $jobedit = JobDetail::find($id);
    $cat = JobCategory::where('id','=',$jobedit->jobcategory_id)->get();

    return View::make('employers.edit_single_jobs')->with('jobedit',$jobedit)
                                                ->with('cat', $cat);
   }
```

**Show page to edit database**

```
    <select name="category[]" class="details">
    <option value="">{{ $jobedit->jobcategory->name }}</option>
    @foreach(JobCategory::all() as $jcat)          
       <option value="{{ $jcat->id }}">{{ $jcat->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
```

My question is, it saves successfully and also edited successfully but when I edit, the selected value from database shows twice in the option value, why it shows twice in the drop-down option value ? If this process of save and edit is not perfect, please help me to show the good process to save and edit. please  help, I am a newbie of learning laravel..

Comment: is it listed twice in your database?

Comment: a post must belongs to one option value...but each post that i want to edit with option value, the selected value of that post shows twice. @Ortix92

Comment: You did not answer my question

Comment: yes, it can be twice thrice or many more in tha database, as a post can be in many categories but it stays with different posts... is it clear? @Ortix92

Comment: Well you have your answer right there. You should not save the same thing multiple times in the database if it belongs multiple models. You should use relationships and a pivot table to assign the values to the model which you require. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: You can use select distinct in your query, but as above, that'd be bad practice, much better to sort db structure properly.

Comment: can u please explain more with example of my code..how can i handle this @i-CONICA

Comment: @user267019 there is no point in going into specific detail with regards to your code. You need to understand SQL and using ORM. Just read eloquent documentation. It will take you at most 30 minutes and everything will become clear. Trust me.